# Error precompiling assets in rails 3. Getting `rake aborted! Unexpected token: keyword (return)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to precompile assets:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'less'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'


# Bundle the extra gems:
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 2.0"
gem 'mini_magick'
gem "geocoder", :require => "geocoder"
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'cancan'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.1"
gem 'thin'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rails-pry'
end

group :production do
  # gem 'mysql2'
  # gem 'ruby-mysql', '~> 2.9.3'
  gem 'exception_notification', :require => 'exception_notifier'
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.11'
end

group :test do
  # gem 'rspec'
  # gem 'rspec-rails'
  # gem 'cucumber'
  # gem 'cucumber-rails'
  # gem 'capybara'
  # gem 'database_cleaner'
  # gem 'webrat'
  # gem 'pickle'
  # gem 'jasmine'
  # gem 'factory_girl'
  # gem 'builder', '~> 2.1.2'
  # gem 'launchy'
  # gem "mocha"
end
# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Stack trace:

```
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
/Users/victorstan/Sites/pop_bottles ∴ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Unexpected token: keyword (return)
  (in /Users/victorstan/Sites/pop_bottles/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:32:in `rescue in block in eval'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:26:in `block in eval'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `block in lock'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1/lib/v8/c/locker.rb:13:in `Locker'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:76:in `lock'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:25:in `eval'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:17:in `exec'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/uglifier-1.2.4/lib/uglifier.rb:101:in `compile'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:20:in `block in compile'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p...]
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@popbottles/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/app`enter code here`lication.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
/Users/victorstan/Sites/pop_bottles ∴
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `pop_bottles/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.  This is not a Heroku problem.